# What does mean "Maximum Heap Size = Unlimited" in a j2me device?

Tags: java, memory, java-me, heap-memory

What does mean "Maximum Heap Size = Unlimited" in a j2me device?
For example of device: 
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/E71/

Can I increase the app's heap size ?

Comment: Not sure (last time i developed j2me applications few years ago), but i think it means that Java VM not limited to some "special" amount of heap and uses whole available RAM of device - as opposed to old j2me-enabled devices which had separate memory limit for native applications and for midlets.

Comment: In NokiaE7 (the above link) The available Native RAM Memory is 128 MB but in the midlet the total memory is = 150 KB

Answer (score 8):

`Heap Memory` means in programming, an area of memory reserved for data that is created at runtime that is, when the program actually executes. In contrast, the stack is an area of memory used for data whose size can be determined when the program is compiled.

Java heap is the heap size allocated to JVM applications which takes care of the new objects being created. If the objects being created exceed the heap size, it will throw an error saying memoryOutof Bound

`Java's default heap size limit is 128MB`. If you need more than this, you should use the -Xms and -Xmx command line arguments when launching your program: 
java -Xms -Xmx

We can also give like in this format also.format is : -mx256m..Sometimes it will show error if you are using

java -Xms -Xmx format..In that case use -mx256m this.value can be changed..